# Validate file exists on server using php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a code which first checks if the variable has value that pulls the image from server and then prints it. If the variable is empty then it prints a default image called nologoyet.png. Following code shows the process

```
<? echo base_url(); ?>logos/<? if($value->logo_file != ""): echo $value->logo_file; else: echo "nologoyet.png"; endif; ?>
```

The above code works perfect. Now my doubt is how do I determine if the file actually exists on the server when the variable is non empty.

Ex. If echo logo_file gives abc.png;
Then I want to check if the abc.png exists on server. If it does not exist then again I want to use nologoyet.png

Reason for the above question is that I can handle every non existent file situation.

Please let me know if a more detailed explanation required. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, just use the file exists function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
     $logo_file = "abc.png";
     $filename = $logo_file;

     if (file_exists($filename)) {
         echo "$filename";
     } else {
         echo "nologoyet.jpg";
     }
```

Comment: I just tried with the following code <? if($value->logo_file != ""): 
         $image_path = base_url().'logos/'.$value->logo_file;
         if(file_exists($image_path)):
          $image_path = base_url().'logos/nologoyet.png';
         endif;
        else:
         $image_path = base_url().'logos/nologoyet.png';
        
        endif;
        clearstatcache();
        ?> But the problem is it is giving true even if the file does not exists. The scenario here is..there is a file called logo33.jpg on the server  ..but the printer one if logo33.jpg, is it like php does not look for extensions?